# Keep original select list when in mobile phone

Tags: jquery, css, select

I am having trouble to keep my original select list when i use a mobile phone.
The original select list is like this:

[image]

In the original select list i am able to type in a search box.
When i use my mobile phone, i get this kind of menu, which is the default for mobile devices.

[image]

What i want, is to use the original select list, even if i use a mobile phone.
I tried to use 'data-role="none"', but no luck.

```
<select class="select form-control" name="mychosen" data-role="none">
```

Comment: The idea of this menu is that it's easier for mobile users to use it in contrast to a select on a desktop/laptop PC. I think it's best not to change that. It's likely less usable, potentially buggy on some mobile devices, and it will go against the expectations of the users.

Comment: Agree with @GolezTrol

Comment: In this case it won't be easier. Some of the lists have more than 400 options. So, by typing it will be much easier for the users.

Comment: I don't know of a way to influence the behaviour of a standard select on mobile, except through some JavaScript trickery (you could replace the select with some custom code), but if you're going to do that, maybe having multiple selects would be easier than typing, for instance first choose brand, then range, then model, narrowing down the search after each selection.